# HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed using Rest webservice

Tags: rest

I am getting correct result when invoking method `@GET`, but as soon as i use `@PUT` method using URI `localhost:8080/MyProject/rest/calculator/23`, it is giving error i.e. `HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed`.

Code is below:

```
@Path("/calculator")
public class CalcyRest {    


    @GET
    @Path("plain/{name}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getplain(@PathParam("name") String name){
        return "this is plain text ... Hello : "+name;
    }

    @GET    
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String getplain(){
        return "<html><head><title></title></head><body><h1>this is html</h1></body> </html>";
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("{studentRollNo}")    
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String updateCal(@PathParam("studentRollNo") String strn){
        return "updated successfully!";
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you didn't really ask a question. You are just describing your problem. Here on SO it is very important to know how to ask a question.

Secondly, it would have been a good idea to have posted the URL for the GET request, in order for us to notice some possible subtle mistakes.

Thirdly, please make sure your request URL is good. I was expecting to see something like `localhost:8080/MyProject/calculator/23`. Why did you put `rest` inside the URL?

Comment: in url mapping of web.xml file i am using rest like <url-mapping>/rest/*</url-mapping>

Comment: btw, do you want to use PUT for updating resources? this would not be RESTful... for updating resources POST should be used

Answer (score 0):

Check your web server configuration. $1 says it is set to reject PUT requests.